# Haskell - defining commutative functions: How to consider actual arguments by combination, not permutation

Tags: haskell

I want to define a function that considers it's equally-typed arguments without considering their order. For example:

```
weirdCommutative :: Int -> Int -> Int
weirdCommutative 0 1 = 999
weirdCommutative x y = x + y
```

I would like this function to actually be commutative. 
One option is adding the pattern:

```
weirdCommutative 1 0 = 999
```

or even better:

```
weirdCommutative 1 0 = weirdCommutative 0 1
```

**Now lets look at the general case:** There could be more than two arguments and/or two values that need to be considered without order - So considering all possible cases becomes tricky.

Does anyone know of a clean, natural way to define commutative functions in Haskell?

I want to emphasize that the solution I am looking for is general and cannot assume anything about the type (nor its deconstruction type-set) except that values can be compared using `==` (meaning that the type is in the `Eq` typeclass but not necessarily in the `Ord` typeclass).

Comment: What is a deconstruction type-set?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is actually [a package](https://github.com/gelisam/commutative) that provides a monad and some scaffolding for defining and using commutative functions. Also see this [blog post.](http://gelisam.blogspot.hu/2013/07/the-commutative-monad.html)

Answer (score 3):

In a case like `Int`, you can simply order the arguments and feed them to a (local) partial function that only accepts the arguments in that canonically ordered form:

```
weirdCommutative x y
  | x > y      = f y x
  | otherwise  = f x y
 where f 0 1 = 999
       f x' y' = x' + y'
```

Now, obviously most types aren't in the `Ord` class – but if you're deconstructing the arguments by pattern-matching, chances are you can define at least some partial ordering. It doesn't really need to be `>`.

Comment: Thanks, but we're not-necessarily dealing with ordered types

Comment: I almost suspected so. Well, you might still be able to use this technique, just try to find some relation that serves the purpose of `>` here.

Comment: You should be able to use any relation where `r x y` implies `not (r y x)` (asymmetry).